# service fabric slow development cycle

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Still very new to service fabric but I'm surprised that something as advanced as this is so slow to debug.  I'm using a fairly fast machine but it takes 4-5 minutes to tear down and restart the cluster.  I've googled it and can't see that anyone else has reported this as being a show stopper.

Comment: Are you talking about a local development cluster? Why should you have to tear it down? When you debug a Service Fabric application the Visual Studio tooling will deploy the application to the local cluster; when you stop debugging the tooling removes the application from the local cluster.

Comment: Do you use SSD? Do you have Antivirus systems\Windows Defender enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Some clues to help with your slow development turnaround time:

- When developing locally, consider using a One-node cluster in order
  to speed-up deployments and upgrades (less Upgrade/Fault Domains):
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster#one-node-and-five-node-cluster-mode
- You need to setup/create your cluster once and than start it and
  keep it running between debugging sessions, Visual Studio will take
  care of uninstalling/upgrading the SF Apps when starting the
  debugger.
- You can modify the properties of the SF Application project to
  decide if your SF App will be uninstalled and install or upgraded
  when starting the debugger, which impacts the deployment time.
- Consider running from a SSD drive which will speed up compilation and
  deployment (file intensive).

Expect less than one minute to compile, deploy and attach debugger for a SF App with 2-3 services.

Comment: There is also this new feature: "Refresh Application" which will speed up your local development. [Read more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/04/17/speed-up-service-fabric-development-with-the-new-refresh-application-debug-mode-2/)

Comment: It's important to also not stuff all your junk into ctors and the like. We have a VS sln with about 30-40 services, and it usually takes around 10 minutes to deploy locally (5-nodes). It's because we're crappy developers and stuff everything constructors.

Comment: @Svend what do you mean by this? Could you give a bad and good example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have the same issue, we have around 10 services in our application and debugging is very slow, VS fails to refresh 1 node cluster all the time, so cluster reset is only solution. So every debug run takes about 5 minutes.

Yes, very disappointment development process, the only advantage is some reuse of C# code, if you have not decided what to use for your cloud solution, abandon C# as early as possible. Go for any JST based language having no intermediate binaries.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing with us. With about 10 services it can take easily 5 minutes to deploy or upgrade app onto local cluster this is already running, and regularly it will fail and have to restart local cluster which takes even longer. Much of the deployment time seems directly correlated with the number of services you are running. So much for "micro" services.
EDIT: And yes, we have reasonably high-end development machines with SSDs.

Comment: Abandoning a C# solution is not an answer. When you inherit a solution with 100+ services, is not an option.